# Read ipfs json from solidity contract

Tags: solidity, ipfs

It is possible to read json value from ipfs file in solidity contract?

Comment: A contract cannot interact directly with anything outside the blockchain. You'll need an oracle that sends the Ipfs file to the contract. Also you should consider that any processing involving strings will be expensive.

Answer (score 3):

This is entirely impossible. Solutions that would come the closest are: relying on oracles to feed in off-chain data, or, having the json data be created on-chain.

Comment: I want to have information about game items, e.g. in json to use in contract. How to do this? Arrays? This is big amount of items (10k)

Comment: Projects have implemented optimised gamified contracts by storing a uint256 as a tokens dna. Best example is to look at https://cryptozombies.io/
If you are looking to use this information in a contract, it must be on-chain. You can then either have the metadata json be created on-chain in the tokenURI function, or retroactively create the metadata (uploaded to ipfs) to match the on-chain information or set up a web-server that will dynamically server metadata jsons by reading on-chain data.

Comment: so how to get information from token metadata?